# anchor element in a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, positioning, overlays

This code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  The initial image\\
  \includegraphics[width=0.6\paperwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  The same image\\
  after some changes have been made\\
  \includegraphics[width=0.6\paperwidth]{example-image-b}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

produces the output

[image]

I would like the image to sit in one place as the text changes on each slide. How to achieve it?

Comment: Look into `overlayarea`, chapter "9.5 Dynamically Changing Text or Images" of the beamer user guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the special case when both your images have the same dimensions, you can simply exchange them:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \alt<1>{The initial image}{The same image}

  \visible<2->{after some changes have been made}

  \includegraphics<1>[width=0.6\paperwidth]{example-image-a}%
  \includegraphics<2->[width=0.6\paperwidth]{example-image-b}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Off-topic:

- you don't need to load `graphicx` with beamer, beamer already provides this functionality
- better use an empty line to indicate a new paragraph